# Create "Ostagram" like Images using Wavelet Transforms

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, wavelet-analysis

I am trying to make an "ostagram" like image using wavelet transforms and image keypoints.

See the following link: https://www.facebook.com/ostagram/

[image]

This is done using neural networks, which I at present am not sure how to implement in Mathematica.

What I am trying to do is the following:

1. Import two images of the same size and type:

   ```
   testImage1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQnFX.jpg"];
   testImage2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAVdX.jpg"];
   ```
2. Segment one image using `ImageKeypoints` with a specific size (in this case 25x25 px) of partitions:

   ```
   ImageSegment[img_, param_] :=
     Module[{i = img, p = param}, 
       ImageTrim[i, {#}, p] & /@ ImageKeypoints[i, "KeypointStrength" -> .001]
      ];
   n = ImageSegment[testImage1, 25];
   ```
3. Use the wavelet transform on one image so that I can extract the detail coefficients and reassemble them into one image:

(*takes the wavelet transform of the second image*)

```
dwd = StationaryWaveletTransform[testImage2, CDFWavelet[], 3];
```

(*only keeps detail coefficients*)

```
detail = InverseWaveletTransform[dwd, Automatic, {___, 1 | 2 | 3}];
Binarize@detail
```

Now, how do I get the segmented images from the first image overlaid on the detailed wavelet coefficients to produce those cool images from the link?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It would help to include example images

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect that this wavelet operation can give anything remotely like the deep neural network images?

Answer (score 6):

A example in the [`StationaryWaveletTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StationaryWaveletTransform.html)(Application/ImageFusion) seem can do this

```
{image, txture} = 
 Import /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQnFX.jpg","https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAVdX.jpg"}
img = Sharpen[image];
txt = ImageMultiply[txture, .5];
{dwdImg, dwdTxt} = 
  StationaryWaveletTransform[#, CDFWavelet[], 3] & /@ {img, txt};
{rval1, rval2} = #[{___, 1 | 2 | 3}, "Values"] & /@ {dwdImg, dwdTxt};
wind = Cases[dwdImg["WaveletIndex"], {___, 1 | 2 | 3}];
nimg = (Image[#1, Interleaving -> False] &) /@ (1/2 (rval1 + 2 rval2));
rnew = MapThread[Rule, {wind, nimg}];
rr = Append[rnew, 
   First[dwdImg[{0, 0, 0}, {"Image", "ImageFunction" -> Identity}]]];
dwdnew = DiscreteWaveletData[rr, CDFWavelet[], 
   StationaryWaveletTransform];
InverseWaveletTransform[dwdnew]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks cool +1.